# Why is Linux giving a pts number for real terminal console? (which is not an emulated terminal like ssh or xterm)

Tags: tty, pty, pts

I read that pts is a pseudo-terminal (that we get through ssh or xterm) and tty is the native terminal.

I didn't connect to my PC through ssh or xterm, but I am still getting pts/0 and pts/1 when I type `who` command. When I open other terminals, the number of pts's increase.

```
username@machine$ who
username tty7         2020-12-30 11:39 (:0)
username pts/0        2020-12-30 11:39 (:0)
username pts/1        2020-12-30 11:53 (:0)
```

I am not getting why this is happening, shouldn't there be more tty's after opening other terminals?

Also, when I do `su` I see that other pts session gets opened for root in auth.log file.

Comment: So how are you connecting and opening these other terminals? `:0` indicates an X session, so you must be using a GUI terminal emulator (if not xterm, then gnome-terminal or something else)

Comment: Okay so the GUI terminal application is also considered as pts and the only tty would be that system's main shell. Like through alt+ctlr+F2 and maybe also through grub. right??

Answer (score 1):

as you already hypothesised in your comment:

> Okay so the GUI terminal application is also considered as pts and the only tty would be that system's main shell. Like through alt+ctlr+F2 and maybe also through grub. right??

a GUI terminal emulator (be it xterm, gnome-terminal etc) does not open a native terminal (tty) but a pseudo-terminal (pts).

native ones are only those that you reach by pressing Alt+Ctrl+F2 etc.

Comment: Okay I got it when we log in we start a tty and all the other terminals like bash, ssh sessions  etc are pseudo-terminals under that tty.

Comment: to the downvoter: please explain why you think this answer is wrong.